# Suppose a spring-mass system satisfies the inital value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, step-function

> $y''+0.25y=k[u_{1.5}(t)-u_{2.5}(t)]$
>
> $y(0)=0$
>
> $y'(0)=0$
>
> where $k$ is a positive parameter.
>
> a) Solve the initial value problem in terms of k.
>
> b) Plot the solution for $k=1/2$, $k=1$, and $k=2$.

For this question I got the solution:

$y(t)=4k[1-cos(0.25t)]u_{1.5}(t-1.5)-4k[1-cos(0.25t)]u_{2.5}(t-2.5)$.

My question is, am I supposed to leave the solution in this form, or is there something I should do with the $u_{1.5}(t-1.5)$ and the $u_{2.5}(t-2.5)$?

If I do leave the solution as it is, for part b, how would I plot this function with $u_{1.5}(t-1.5)$ and the $u_{2.5}(t-2.5)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this for the first question:
$$y(t)=4k u_{3/2}\left(1-\cos \left(\frac 12 (t-\frac 32)\right)\right)-4ku_{5/2}\left (1-\cos \left(\frac 12 (t-\frac 52)\right)\right)$$

Since we have :
$$\mathcal {L^{-1}}\{e^{-cs}F(s)\}=u(t-c)f(t-c)$$
$$\mathcal {L^{-1}}\left \{\dfrac s {s^2+1/4}\right\}=\cos (t/2)$$

Comment: Oh, okay, I know what I did wrong. But how did you get $cos(1/2(t-3/2))$ and $cos(1/2(t-5/2))$? Shouldn't it be $cos(1/4(t-3/2))$ and $cos(1/4(t-5/2))$?

Comment: You need to shift the cosine function and note that $a^2=1/4 \implies a=1/2$  @Not2Scary  What's your value of $a^2$ ?

Comment: Right! Thank you! Do you know how I would go about plotting this with the different values of k?

Comment: @Not2Scary No I just solved first question and checked your result.

Comment: You can plot it on DESMOS for different values of k....@Not2Scary Take a look here https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: I think what I'm confused about is how to incorporate $u_{3/2}$ and $u_{5/2}$ into the graph.

Comment: Oh it simple it means it zero for $t<3/2$ and the normal cosine graph It's just Heaviside function...  @Not2Scary

Comment: Ooh, okay. Thank you, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Not2Scary you're welcomed